# Sorting data in a table generated from CSV

Tags: javascript, sorting, csv, d3.js, html-table

I am trying to sort out the table that I have generated from CSV file using d3.js, but when using the following code only first row gets sorted and everything else gets ignored. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
d3.text("resources/data.csv", function(data) {
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data).sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a.HomeTeam > b.HomeTeam) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (a.HomeTeam < b.HomeTeam) {
                    return -1;
                }
                // a must be equal to b
                return 0;
            });
            //var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

            var container = d3.select("body")
                .append("table");

            var tr = d3.selectAll("tr").data(parsedCSV);

            tr.enter().append("tr");

                    tr.selectAll("td")
                      .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                      .append("td")
                      .text(function(d) { return d; });
        });
```

I am using D3.js library to parse the CSV file and to generate a table using the data from CSV.

Comment: note: i want to use parsedCSV later to create a scatterplot from it so I would like the data to be sorted and stored in parsedCSV

Comment: Note that CSV parsing doesn't automatically convert numbers to numbers, so the `<` comparison may just return the same result in all cases. If `HomeTeam` is a number, you need to convert it (e.g. `+d.HomeTeam`).

Comment: Yeah, home team is a string, the thing is i will be using this data i pull out of csv to generate a match/position scatterplot, and since entries are a bit messed up i want to save me some tinkering about the algorithm to draw this and sort the data according to values in HomeTeam and AwayTeam columns, so i would first draw out a graph for one team, then second and so on. That's why the sort is in, table is just there for trial and error to see if i got the sort right. I am getting the data from here > http://football-data.co.uk/englandm.php, just to clear out the format i have

Comment: If they are strings you need to use something like [`.localeCompare()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp) for the comparison.

Comment: I see, so if statement should be something like this: if a.HomeTeam.localeCompare(b.HomeTeam) = some number according to my case then return certain number to sort function?

Comment: Yea, according to doc you linked it should, i will try that thanks a lot, edit actually i dont even need the if statement anymore